# Find a unique $f^*\in C([0,1])$ s.t. $g+R(f)=f$ where $f,g,R(f):[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Here $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and so is $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. $R(f)$ is a little bit more complicated:
\begin{equation}
R(f)(x):=\int_0^x k(x,y)f(y)dy
\end{equation}
for a continuous $k: [0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ (we take the standard metric on $[0,1]^2\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ i.e. the Euclidean Metric/Distance Function).
I have managed to prove that $R(f): [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

My initial idea was to solve it through Banach's fixed point theorem; for that I need to prove, however, that $R(f)$ is Lipschitz-continuous with a Lipschitz-constant $L<1$. I have not been able to prove that this far.

If $R$ turns out to have a L.C. $L<1$, then I will be able to utilize a variant of the Banach's fixed point theorem to prove the assertion. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I think you need to edit the title, who is $g$? is one of the $f$s meant to be $f^*$?

Comment: You need more information about $k$ in order to prove the claim on $[0,1]$. You can, however, find $\epsilon>0$ such that $f$ exists on $[0,\epsilon]$, at least.

Comment: @Ramitaラミタ Yes, the $f^*$ is meant to be one of the $f$s.

Comment: @zugzug The only thing I know about the $k$ is that it is continuous. I, however, will edit my post to say that it is continuous regarding the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e. the euclidean metric.

Comment: I could prove that k is Lipschitz, but I don't see why $L <1.$

Comment: @BokaPeer I could be wrong in my solution. It was just the best idea/ only idea I had to prove the assertion.  Do you perhaps have another way in mind?

Comment: Hint : by iterating the integral equation, you get the expression for $f$ as a series of integrals of $g$ and $k$

Comment: @SolubleFish I am sorry, I am afraid I don't quite understand. Do you mean to apply integration by parts in the definition of $R(f)$? If so, how can we ensure that either $k$ or $f$ are differentiable (which is necessary for the integration by parts)? Or which integral equation do you mean?

Comment: I wrote it down in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's proceed formally to find an expression for $f$.

The equation is rewritten $(\text{id} - R)(f) = g$, whose solution is :
$$f = (\text{id} - R)(g) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty R^n(g)$$

If we had $\|R \|<1$ this would be over, but this is not the case. To show that the series actually converges uniformly, notice that:
\begin{align}
R^n(g) (x_0) &= \int_0^{x_0} \text{d}x_1 \ldots \int_0^{x_{n-1}} \text{d}x_n \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} k(x_i,x_{i+1}) g(x_n) \\
|R^n(g) (x_0)|& \leqslant (\|k \|_\infty)^n\|g\|_\infty  \int_0^{x_0} \text{d}x_1 \ldots \int_0^{x_{n-1}} \text{d}x_n  1  \\
& \leqslant(\|k \|_\infty)^n\|g\|_\infty  \text{vol}\left(\{(x_i) |0\leq x_n \leq x_{n-1}\leq \ldots \leq x_0\}\right)\\
& \leqslant \frac{x^n(\|k \|_\infty)^n}{n!}\|g\|_\infty 
\end{align}

Therefore, $\| R^n \|\leqslant \frac{(\|k\|_\infty)^n}{n!}$ and the series $\sum R^n(g)$ converges in $\mathcal C^0([0,1])$

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have a couple of questions: In your proof of $|R^n(f)(x_0)|\leq\dots$ you mean $f$ not $g$ right (on the right hand side)? Secondly: You say that the norm of $R^n$ is $\leq |k|^n_{\infty}/n!$ -- you came to that conclusion because:  $x^n\leq 1$ and the norm of $g$ is less than or equal to 1, correct?

Comment: Or  did I not fully understand your proof?

Comment: I added a few lines to make it clear where the $n!$ comes from

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the proof now :)